# Unity 2017.4.1f1 Spawned GameObject not visible by client (networking)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

I have a Zombie Controller GameObject with ZombieController script attached. It uses the following function to spawn a zombie. My host can see the zombies, but the client cannot.

```
void Update() {
    slider.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { ValueChangeCheck(); });
    int spawnPointNumber = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length); // exclusive of maximum

    spawnTimer += Time.deltaTime;
    if (spawnTimer > spawnWaitTime) {
        GameObject spawnPoint = spawnPoints[spawnPointNumber];
        Vector3 worldSpawnPosition = spawnPoint.transform.position;
            if (zombiesLeft < maxZombies) {
                CmdSpawnZombie(worldSpawnPosition);
            }
        spawnTimer = 0f;
    }
}
    [Command]
private void CmdSpawnZombie(Vector3 worldSpawnPosition) {
    int zombieNumber = Random.Range(0, zombiePrefabs.Length);// exclusive of maximum
    zombiePrefab = zombiePrefabs[zombieNumber];

    GameObject zombie = Instantiate(zombiePrefab, worldSpawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    zombie.transform.SetParent(this.gameObject.transform);
    zombie.gameObject.name = zombiePrefab.gameObject.name;
    zombiesLeft++;
    NetworkServer.Spawn(zombie);
}
```

ZombieController.cs is inheriting NetworkBehaviour.

The ZombieController, and all zombiePrefabs have Network Identities attached (tick-boxes are not ticked). The zombiePrefabs also have Network Transforms (and apparently Network send rate should be set to 0 here? I've tried non zero, but still doesn't work)

[image]

The zombiePrefabs (and even the Zombie Controller) are attached to the Network Manager 'Registered Spawnable Prefabs'

I've checked the client hierarchy, and the zombies are definitely not spawning!
I'm not sure what else to try. 
Any help would be great!
thanks guys

Comment: Can you add the piece of code where you call this function?

Comment: @captainCrazy added the code :)

Comment: I'm guessing the ZombieController is not a Player. If that's the case, it needs to have local player authority in order to call Commands. It has a checkbox in the Network Identity component.